# LED light strip at a distance from power

Tags: led

Can I use 18 ga thermostat wire running 25' carrying 12vdc to power 2 12vdc commercial strip lights with 30 leds in each strip.? My concern is that there will be a voltage drop over the 25' wire which is running from a 12 volt wet cell.

Comment: Do you have any way of finding out or measuring how much current each strip is drawing?

Answer (score 1):

**Short:**

No problem

**Longer:**

Assuming "thermostat wire" is standard stranded copper wire, 18 gauge wire has a resistance of about 0.021 Ohm/meter ~= 0.064 Ohm/foot.

A 25 foot run with go and return wires = 25 x 2 x 0.064 = 3.2 Ohms.
 This will drop 3.4 V per ampere. To start alaloow say 5V/A to allow for connectors etc.

LEDs are often operated at a nominal 20 mA but this is not certain in this case.
12V strip with White LEDs at 3v to 3.3V/LED will (or should have 3 LEDs in series).
Red LEDs at 2.xV/LED may have 4 or 5 LEDs in series.

So a 30 LED strip of white LEDs may be arranged as 3S10P = 3 x 10 LEDs
At 20 mA LED it will draw 20 mA per series string of 3 LEDs or 200 mA for the string.

At 5V/A drop 200 mA will drop 1A = well within normal range of operation.
 If your strings have ointernal constant current drivers they will operate without visible effect. If not (whch is more likely) there will be a decrease in light output which would be essentially undetectable by eye.

[Wikipedia - AWG - Wire tables and related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) - usefully gives formulae for derivation of wire size and resistance etc from wire-gauge.

[Also usefu here](http://www.stealth316.com/2-wire-resistance.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Considering a 12V wet cell is 12~13.5 and 14.2V on charger, if you use a 12V 1500mA wall transformer, that should work reasonably well with lossy wire in the 2~6 Ohm range.  The wet cell is redundant then, *except as emergency standby lighting power.*  The wall transformer will drop to 12V at rated current and run higher with less load.

My guess is they are 5050 SMD chips 30 per 8mm reel 7.2Wmax at 12.0V like [these.](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Waterproof-RGB-LED-String-light-Flexible-SMD-5050-IP65-30LEDs-1M-24K-IR-Control-/251065395231?pt=US_String_Lights_Fairy_Lights&hash=item3a74a9e81f)

These LED's already have series resistors in each circuit of 3 ~ 6 depending on color which affects Vf drop, so the voltage is not as critical but will affect brightness a bit. I would suggest at the load end that if you read 12V +/0.5V is perfect and >+/-1V should be adjusted.

I recently did the same with AWG20 x 35ft wire and wall-transformer per above for my yagi antenna to get HDTV 145 miles away.... just for pizazz..
[image]
Moving camera effect
[image]
Two strings of LEDs plus a RED stop light the corner reflector. 12V @1.3A = 15W.
The DC wires got wrapped around coax and fed thru an access hole into basement ( then plugged up to keep the bugs out. )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but a very large thank you from me, Balou.  My solution was to run 16/2 stranded wire to a box and then run two 30 natural white LED arrays from a 16/2 lead to each.  My 18 gauge is solid wire and they will each only be running 6 LEDs in window candles so we'll choose a more yellow/orange color.  The wiring will be done this weekend but the test is still out there 60 days when the house is completed.  Interestingly (to me) this wiring has to be inspected.  Go figure.

My sincere thanks for the help.

Balou